# ViewDataBinding getVariable?

Tags: android, android-databinding

The 2 main questions are :

- Why [ViewDataBinding](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding.html) doesn't have a method like `getVariable("variableName")` that will look up for a variable and returns it or null if no variable with this name exists.
- Is their any way/workaround to achieve this kind of behavior?

So to be more explicit : if I don't know the type of my [ViewDataBinding](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding.html), is their a way to get its variable or I must know its type?

---

**Here is how it is working actually :**

1. I havea layout called **my_layout.xml** :

```xml
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable
            android:name="myVaribale"
            android:type="String"/>
        </variable>
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/root_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@{myVariable}"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
<layout>
```

2. I inflate an instance of its [ViewDataBinding](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding.html) :

   ```
   MyLayoutBinding binding = (MyLayoutBinding) DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.my_layout, root, false);
   ```
3. I can get its variable by calling the appropriate method :

   ```
   String myVariable = binding.getMyVariable();
   ```

So this was how to get a variable when **we know the type** of the [ViewDataBinding](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding.html).

---

**My problem is here :**

Let's imagine I have 3 layouts called `my_layout_1`, `my_layout_2`, `my_layout_3` and those 3 layouts are surrounded by a `<layout>` tag.
Those 3 layouts has also the same variable (`myVariable`).

So here are the layouts :

**my_layout_1**

```
<layout>

    <data>
        <variable
            android:name="myVariable"
            android:type="String"/>
        </variable>
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/root_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@{myVariable}"
            style="@style/my_style_1"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

<layout>
```

**my_layout_2**

```
<layout>

    <data>
        <variable
            android:name="myVariable"
            android:type="String"/>
        </variable>
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/root_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@{myVariable}"
            style="@style/my_style_2"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

<layout>
```

**my_layout_3**

```
<layout>

    <data>
        <variable
            android:name="myVariable"
            android:type="String"/>
        </variable>
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/root_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@{myVariable}"
            style="@style/my_style_3"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

<layout>
```

So the different layout represent a text with a different style (I know it can be achieved by others way but the goal is just to explain why I need this function `getVariable(variableName)`.

Imagine now that I got a layout called `my_text_container` which will randomly contain one of the 3 layouts.

**my_text_container**

```
<layout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<layout>
```

So I'll add a text by doing something like this (again, it's just for demonstration purpose) :

```
MyTextContainerBinding textContainerBinding = (MyTextContainerBinding) DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.my_text_container, root, false);
int textLayoutRes;
int randomNumber = generateNumberBetween0and2();
switch(randomNumber) {
    case 0: textLayoutRes = R.layout.my_layout_1;
        break;
    case 1: textLayoutRes = R.layout.my_layout_2;
        break;
    case 2: textLayoutRes = R.layout.my_layout_3;
        break;
}
textContainerBinding.getRoot().addView(DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, textLayoutRes, root, false));
```

And finally I want to retrieve `myVariable` but I don't know if it's a layout 1, 2 or 3. Basically what could be done now is to use [instanceof](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13155_01/wlp/docs103/javadoc/com/bea/p13n/expression/operator/Instanceof.html) operator to check whether its a type `MyLayoutBinding1`, `MyLayoutBinding2` or `MylayoutBinding3`. But as I said this use-case is only for demonstration purpose and I could have 999 different layouts.

So what I would like to do is :

```
ViewDataBinding myLayout = DataBindingUtil.getBinding(textContainerBinding.getRoot().getChildAt(0));
String myVariable = myLayout.getVariable("myVariable");

if(myVariable != null)
    Log.d(TAG, "myLayout was MylayoutBinding1 or myLayoutBinding2 or myLayoutBinding3");
else
    Log.d(TAG, "mylayout was not one of the 3 layouts");
```

Sorry for this (very) long post but thank's for reading it and for any future answers !

Comment: The right answer, from a Java perspective, would be for you to be able to request that all three `MyLayoutBinding...` classes implement a common interface, where you have your `getMyVariable()`. I do not see where that is an option, though you could file a feature request for it.

Comment: When you decide which layout to inflate by setting `textLayoutRes`, you already know which layout you have chosen. I can't find any reason why you want an extra `getMyVariable()` when you already know about inflated layout file. As layout files cannot be dynamic so you'll always know how many layouts you have. And you'll have to cast them and set variables for every layout binding. So the problem is still unclear what do you want to achieve. I would suggest you, to get a better answer, post the actual problem and explain with it why you need this.

Comment: Google should really add this feature.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if I get it but what I do is I declare a variable in the layout like this:

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="variableName"
        type="bla.bla.VariableType"/>
</data>
```

Then first you get your layout binding in onCreate:

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
```

Then you should send a variable to the layout in code like:

```
binding.setVariableName(yourVariable);
```

Then you can retrieve it like:

```
binding.getVariableName();
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know which child ViewDataBinding I'll get so their will be no generated methods for variable. But I know that for whatever ViewDataBinding I'll get I'll have a variable with the same name (let's say "foo") so what I wants is to write something like : 

ViewDataBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.your_layout, container, false);

binding.getVariable("foo");
That could throw NullPointerException if the layout doesn't have something like

<data>
    <variable
        name="Foo"
        type="FooType"/>
</data>

Comment: try binding.getFoo() in that case. Is that what you want?

Comment: No because binding will be declared as ViewDataBinding and not as MyLayoutDataBinding (which is a child of ViewDataBinding).

Comment: If your layout is called R.layout.your_layout, you should have: YourLayoutBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.your_layout, container, false);

Then you should be able to find the variable as I described.

Comment: I know but let's imagine I got R.layout.my_layout and R.layout.my_layout_2. Both as a variable named "foo". I want to have a method where in arguments I pass a "ViewDataBinding" that is either a MyLayoutBinding or MyLayout2Binding and then call a method like getVariable("foo").

Comment: Is it because you have many binding variables and you want to do it generic? How about checking if the ViewDataBinding is an instance of MyLayoutBinding or MyLayout2Binding and then calling .getFoo() to that instance?

Comment: This would work sure. I wanted to create something dynamic where I don't have to add a "case" statement if I add a new layout but maybe this is not possible. Thx for help btw.

Comment: Sure no problem :)

Answer (score -1):

1. why ViewDataBinding Doesn't have getMethodVariable?

   consider the normal scenario without binding. you have a text container layout. how will you include another layout inside it in a normal activity.

my_text_container.xml:(Normal activity)

You inflate this layout to your java file using R.layout.my_text_container, you won't inflate every layout to a different view to access textview inside it. just one inflate  and go with it.

So the same procedure is followed in DataBinding as well, when you use include tag ,the respective fields will be inside MyTextContainerLayoutBinding. 
you don't have to inflate it again and again with activity name like MyLayout1Binding, MyLayout2Binding. that's why getting variable name become unnecessary over here.

**I think adding variability to Binding , will be more helpful in a place where you just want to display data. Data from one model across multiple included layouts,more helpful with Listviews,Recyclerviews(where layout use data from models).**

you can't provide different type for different layouts ,if  you are going include one layout to another.(Remember that this binds both layout to single name (parent_activity in your case container)).

Eg:

**UserProfileModel:**

```
public class UserProfileModel {

    String firstname;
    String lastname;

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
```

}

**my_layout_1.xml;**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
   <data>
    <variable name="user"
             type="com.hourglass.lingaraj.bindingusingvariables.UserProfileModel" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@{user.firstname}"
    style="@style/mystyle_1"/>


        <include layout ="@layout/my_layout_2"
            app:user="@{user}" />
</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

**my_layout_2.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="user"
            type="com.hourglass.lingaraj.bindingusingvariables.UserProfileModel"/>
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{user.lastname}"
            style="@style/mystyle_2"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MyLayout1Binding layout_binding;
    UserProfileModel data_model;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout_1);
        data_model  = new UserProfileModel();
        data_model.setFirstname("Lingaraj");
        data_model.setLastname("Sankaravelu");

        layout_binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(getLayoutInflater(),R.layout.my_layout_1,null,false);
        layout_binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.my_layout_1);
        layout_binding.setUser(data_model);
        }
}
```

As you see we are using only one model to populate data across included layout. So there is no need get Variable name to verify which model is loaded as it's Binded to single layout.

2. There is no workaround to achieve this, us of I have tried.

**So my answer will be No you can't get a variable name from binding**

**References.**

[No More findViewById](https://medium.com/google-developers/no-more-findviewbyid-457457644885#.9vyinw83q)

[Android Data Binding: That  Thing](https://medium.com/google-developers/android-data-binding-that-include-thing-1c8791dd6038#.qwjw1gee7)

[Android Data Binding: Adding some variability](https://medium.com/google-developers/android-data-binding-adding-some-variability-1fe001b3abcc#.vssvk1kqx)

[Android Data Binding: Express Yourself](https://medium.com/@georgemount007/android-data-binding-express-yourself-c931d1f90dfe#.ev4etu4fs)

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.

Comment: Also, your post does not answer the question.

Comment: I have read these articles before, and there is no information about a dynamically/generic accessing of variables in a generic `ViewDataBinding` just by knowing the name of the variable as provided as an example in the question. Please proof me wrong, because this would be an amazing feature.

Comment: I am not aware of a solution, but I am waiting for George Mount or Ygit Boyar to reply this, because they created the `DataBinding` for android. As I said, a `getVariable` feature would be really nice. You only have posted links - so you are not providing a solution per se. And why should I answer, if I don't have one? You are starting to get rude. ;)